# POST request not working, page keeps loading

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

so im building my first app using express and mongoDB, and i am having some troubles with authentication, i used the MEAN web development book to build the structure of my folders following the MVC pattern, and then i started with this tutorial and tried to build oauth authentication, but before starting really doing the oauth stuff i get stuck on the local authentication, wen i try to submit the form it keeps loading all the time and never gives me a response, with postman i get a **Could not get any response**, i don't know what can cause this problem, since i have a lot of code and i have no idea what kind of error can cause this i will place here my gitProject.

**folder structure:**

[image: folder structure]

**git:**[project](https://github.com/FilipeCosta/MeanStackBook)

**i feel the problem can rely on how i pass the passport module:**

**.config/express**

```
var config          = require('./config');
var express         = require('express');
var passport        = require('passport');
var flash           = require('connect-flash');
var compress        = require('compression');
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var session         = require('express-session');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var morgan          = require('morgan');
var methodOverride  = require('method-override');
var expressLayouts  = require('express-ejs-layouts');

module.exports = function(){
    var app = express();

    require('./passport')(passport);

    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    {
        app.use(morgan('dev'));
    }  
    else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
    {
        app.use(compress());

    }
    app.use(cookieParser());

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
       extended:true 
    }));
    app.use(morgan('dev'));

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride());

    app.use(session({
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true,
        secret: 'keyboard'
    }));



    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
    app.use(flash());

    app.set('views', './app/views');
    app.set('view engine','ejs');
    app.use(expressLayouts);



    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app,passport);
    require('../app/routes/register.server.routes.js')(app,passport);
    require('../app/routes/login.server.routes.js')(app,passport);
    require('../app/routes/profile.server.routes.js')(app,passport);
    app.use(express.static('./public'));
    return app;
}
```

**..app/routes/register.server.routes.js**

```
var register = require('../../app/controllers/register.server.controller');
module.exports = function(app,passport) {
 app.route('/register')
 .post(function(req,res){
      passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/register', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
  })})
 .get(register.getPage);
};
```

Comment: if it keeps reloading means there could be a case of infinite recursion. is it that on failure you return the user to /register which again calls /register and so on?

Comment: but in my way of thing it shouldn't do that, i have a get request to /register and a post to /register, the second is activated with the form submit, so it shouldn't be in a infinite recursion :S

Comment: you are right, that's how it should be. I suspected on load of page you might be making a default post call.

Comment: you can test by our own the app with my gitproject, its hard for me as a newbie to know exactly where the error can be in this situation sorry :/

Comment: Another thing is I am not sure how this passport redirect is working, usually we use res.redirect etc. But then again its just a  guess.

Comment: i have it inside the passport, the successReditect and the failureRedirect, but it doesn't redirect me to nowhere :S

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: false
}))
```

Instead of:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}))
```